# Using Python to read three sets of data in three different stations

Tags: python

I have a file like this (data.txt):

[image]

Each column contains data from 3 different stations (1,2,3..1,2,3..so on), so now I want to read the data from each station 1(line 1, line 4, line 7), station 2 (line 2, line 5, line 8) and station 3 (line 3, line 6, line 9)....

How could I do? My appologies if someone had asked before.

Thanks

Comment: paste the data as the original text-file, not as a picture. Then it's easier for people to help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your data is comma delimited this will work:

```
with open('data.txt') as d:
    data = [list(map(float, line.split(','))) for line in d]
    station1 = data[::3] #from first with step 3
    station2 = data[1::3] #from second with step 3
    station3 = data[2::3] #from third with step 3
    print station1
    print station2
    print station3
```

However, if you use other delimiter change `split()` argument to it's value.

**EDIT**

You must be using `Python 3.x` so you need to convert map into list. In `3.x` `map()` returns iterator.

Answer (score 1):

```
with open("myfile.txt") as f:
    lines = [line.rstrip('\n').split(" ") for line in f]


station_1_data = lines[0::3]

station_2_data = lines[1::3]

station_3_data = lines[2::3]
```

Comment: It does not work. May you offer further help? Thanks

Comment: in what way doesn't it work? Are you getting an error message or is the output not the correct format?

Comment: I got something like this: [<map object at 0x00000000061E4240>, <map object at 0x00000000063E2EF0>, <map object at 0x00000000063FE240>,

Comment: ok I've edited my answer with a few improvements. I've mocked it up on my laptop and it seems to be working fine, there shouldn't be any `map` objects being created in the solution I've given so I'm not too sure where they are coming from